# Java SEVERE Application Errors

Tags: java

I installed jre-7u51-linux (32bit) due to application instructions in PCRAnyWhere, a application that displays a graphic radio console and sends/receives messages to control a ICOM digital radio. Any insight from Java guys/gals about the errors.

```
Do you wish to run the configuration utility now? [Yes]/No: Yes
Mar 09, 2017 2:27:26 PM org.jdesktop.application.Application$1 run
SEVERE: Application class pcrconfig.PCRConfig failed to launch
java.awt.HeadlessException
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:233)
at org.jdesktop.application.FrameView.getFrame(FrameView.java:44)
at org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication.getMainFrame(SingleFrameApplication.java:125)
at pcrconfig.PCRConfig.startup(PCRConfig.java:18)
at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:171)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Application class pcrconfig.PCRConfig failed to launch
at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:177)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(    ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:204)
at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:536)
at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:233)
at org.jdesktop.application.FrameView.getFrame(FrameView.java:44)
at org.jdesktop.application.SingleFrameApplication.getMainFrame(SingleFrameApplication.java:125)
at pcrconfig.PCRConfig.startup(PCRConfig.java:18)
at org.jdesktop.application.Application$1.run(Application.java:171)
... 14 more
```

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: You really should be going to PCRAnyWhere support, not here.

Comment: I did, but those people are out to lunch. If the errors are due to installation then it is my fault.

Comment: If you post more details about your environment and elaborate further, we might be able to help more. The implied question (shouldn't imply around here; ask explicitly) is still answerable though, so I have answered.

Comment: I meant to say here that I requested a login id to ask this question, but I think that they are hobbyists who are not around much of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You got a HeadlessException. This generally means just what it sounds like; you are running in a headless environment.

Are you running this on a headless system, that is, on a system without user interface devices attached, such as a monitor? Or is it in a virtual machine which is (virtually) headless? SSH'ed to a machine without X forwarded? Something along these lines is probably your issue; it's likely a hardware thing (whether real or virtual hardware), not a software thing.

Comment: The machine is what I would consider a standard setup. Monitor, keyboard,mouse. Linux 4.10 compiled with gcc-6.3. Been using it for more than 2 years. But not anything with java so far.

Comment: Do you have a standard graphics environment, or is it a command-line-only distribution?

Comment: It is a standard distribution Fedora 23-64 running with kernel 4.10. I have tested the graphics with Mesa 3D Graphics, built from source. I wanted to try out PCRAnywhere with a a new/old stock ICOM radio receiver. It that works then I was going to write my own application with a non-java method.

Comment: If you are running a full, normal setup with mouse/keyboard/monitor and a modern graphics environment (such as Gnome), then I do not know why the application thinks you have a headless environment. Sorry.

Comment: My question over at www.pcranywhere has been viewed a few times but no replies.